# Nop 4.1 New GUEST user is getting created once payment is completed

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

Expected behvior:

Just like a registered user, a guest user is also expected to come back to order details page or checkout completed (if enable) page after a successful payment.

Actual behavior:

However, the guest user when "guest checkout is enabled" won't bring back user to the order details or checkout completed page. It's taking user back to home page.

Location:
What I noticed is that the "InsertGuestCustomer" from CustomerService is getting called after redirect.

Same behavior on below browsers:
1. Chrome
2. Firefox
3. IE

Steps to reproduce:

1. Enable any plugin that does URL redirect.
2. Enable one-page-checkout
3. Enable guest checkout
4. Start adding items to cart
5. Checkout using OPC page
6. Confirm and wait for PG to redirect back to site.

I am facing this on both localhost and hosted site.

Note: I am running SSL on localhost & using RemotePost to submit form to payment gateway.

Comment: Is this a question or an error report? https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/issues

Comment: I am not sure, it could be a setting issue. Anyway, will report it in the github.

Comment: @MarcoRegueira it's a bug. I have received message from others saying they are faicng the same issue.